# Is it possible to integrate/access Node.JS inside a Qt application?

Tags: node.js, qt, qtwebkit

More specifically, I have a QWebView inside my Qt application and would like Node.JS to run inside pages displayed inside it. I have a bridge between the web view and my application, so I'm able to run Javascript commands inside the web view which communicate with the application.

I'm wondering if it's possible to make Node.JS available to the web view to use?

Answer (score 1):

Node.js typically starts up a web server of sorts, at least in some of the applications I've tried.  So accessing the localhost with the appropriate port name should not be a problem.

So basically, start Node.js on port 9000 for example, then open the webview to `http://localhost:9000/` and you should be good to go.  If you want to have a headless way to access the webserver or its sockets or rest/soap interfaces, you should be able to do it pretty easily with the `QNetworkAccessManager` class and its related support classes.

Hope that helps.